# Target group health checks fail AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

I am pretty new to AWS

I have a Golang app deployed on Elasticbeanstalk. All worked fine when it was a single instance app, without using load balancing.

However, when I introduce a load balancer, I cannot access a website at all.

The app is running on port 8080.

Here is my elastic beanstalk listeners configuration

[image]

Also, here is ALB configuration:

[image]

Target group health check fails with Request timeout. It's configured to route / which should work.

Security groups should be fine, I've create inbound rules for ports 5432 (need it for postgres), 8080 etc. All worked fine on single instance environment

Now, I am not able to access my app via port 8080 (nor via 80 nor via 443 - ssl), of course not via custom domain

I did not include details of certificate and custom domain on purpose, wanted to isolate this problem

What can be an issue and how can I debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved

There were wrong subnets specified on Elasticbeanstalk

When I created min 1, max 2 instances and specified 2 subnets in 2 availability zones, all started working fine

There was no issue in Security groups nor Targets

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

As the Target Group Health check is failing with `Request timeout`, this could be a Security Group issue.

Check the Security Group rules attached to EC2 Instances and ELB and ensure that ELB can connect to the EC2 instance.

- ELB Security Group needs an Outbound rule for port 8080 to the VPC range or the Security Group attached to EC2 instances.
- EC2 Security Group needs an Inbound rule for port 8080 to the VPC range or SecurityGroup attached to ELB.

You can refer [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-fix-failing-health-checks-alb) for more detailed instructions under `Target.Timeout` section.

Comment: Thanks. Tried this but it does not work. Worth mentioning that ELB and EC2 are in same VPC. Also, I already had a outboung rule in ELB security group for port 8080 all addresses (0.0.0.0/0). Now I also included the one for VPC block - 172.31.0.0/16 
The same for inbound rule on EC2. It there something else I could check?

Is it normal that Ec2 instances does not have public ip address after adding load balancer?

Comment: Yes, having a public IP to EC2 instances is not mandatory when they are behind ELB. Is your application up and running? Are you able to connect to the application from within the instance and from any other instance in the same VPC?

Comment: No, accessing to original_elasticbeanstalk_url:8080 also return 502

I did not yet try from within instance, will check

But all worked fine before introducing load balancer

Comment: I just created a new ec2 instance which has public ip address with same vpc as the instance where server is running. Tried `curl http://<private ip address where server is running>:8080` and I got `Failed to connect to ip-172-31-21-70.ec2.internal port 80 after 3 ms: Couldn't connect to server`
Does it mean something @sudheerchamarthi

Comment: UPDATE: I moved back to single instance and then again moved to load balanced environment, but this time as max instances 2 (previously was 1) and specified exactly 2 subnets in 2 different availability zones. Now I can access my environment over port 80 just fine (http), it redirects to 8080 on the target instance
However, ssl is not working, using custom domain. I followed all the steps when creating domain, got a certificate but site is not reachable DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN